# Configuration .net core web application and webapi on IIS

Tags: c#, iis, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm in progress a create my web application (WebUI) and webapi (WebApi). In ASP.Net I have always worked that way create web application on IIS with path to result debug folder, and WebApi as web application inside webside. In Visual Studio attach process w3wp.exe and I could debug the code. I would like to achieve the same effect now.

Now I have WebUI (Web application .net Core 2.2) and WebApi (web api .net Core 2.2). In IIS add new Site (path to WebUi Debug folder) and inside create application (path to WebApi Debug folder)

my routing

```
[Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
    }
```

Desired effect:

http://localhost:8100/ - website

http://localhost:8100/webapi/api/v1/values - endpoint webapi

website it works but WebApi not. I need to use site and api at the same time. When I run Web Api in Visual Studio web Api work correct. Any advice or a better idea for debug in the same time? Everything work fine when application web api in iis navigate to publish webapi.

Comment: I find it easier to just use different port number for both website and API. I'm sure what you're trying to do is achievable but never seen it done for a dotnet core api project before. Also not worth it IMO.

Comment: IIS paths should navigate to ..\..\WebAPI\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2 ? Now site return 503 error and api return 404.0 error. All path nawigate to netcoreapp2.2 (different for site and api) I should change enything in configuration solution or RouteConfig.cs? - erly I used default settings

Comment: Did you try below answer?

Comment: unfortunately your solution not working. In my solution Api I do not have WebApiConfig. Only Startup.cs

Answer (score 0):

Try this in RouteConfig.cs.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Home",
    url: "",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

And for api routes in WebAPiConfig.cs

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

On the other hand you can define route directly in Api Controller like this.

```
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("webapi/api/v1/values")]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

Good luck.